# Using loops for Selection dialog box (if, elseif, else)

Tags: windows, matlab

I am trying to create a conditional loop based on the answers from my selection dialog box in Matlab. But i dont know the actual code for it.

Tried some trial and error but no luck.

```matlab
list = {'Raw water','Treated Water','Sample water'};
[indx,tf] = listdlg('PromptString','Select water type:','SelectionMode','single','ListString',list);
```

**I want to provide 3 different conditions for each selection from my selection dialog box.**

Comment: why dont you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Irreducible

I am a complete beginner in this. I have tried this at the latest. This is just an example: 
if 
    indx = 1;
    disp('LOL')
elseif
    indx = 2;
    disp('LMAO')
else
    disp('ROFL')
end


My main querry is how do i relate the selection inside the loop?

Comment: Hint: your expression is not correct, check the help on `if,else, else if `, or in other word there is a difference between comparing two values and assigning a value to variable